# implicit partial differentiation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> $f=\frac{x+2y}{2y-x}$ ,$x=2u-3v$  ,$y=u+2v$
>
> Find $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$ ,$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$

I can find $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}$ and the same of  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$

What I did it to subtitle $f=\frac{x+2y}{2y-x}=\frac{2u-3v+2u+4v}{2u+4v-2u+3v}=\frac{4u+v}{7v}=\frac{4u}{7v}+\frac{1}{7}$

and than $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}=\frac{-4u}{7v^2}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}=\frac{4}{7v}$

Is this a vaild move?

Answer (score 1):

Your method seems ok. However, note:

$$ 2y - x = 7v$$

Also, to find $\frac{df}{dv}$, you need to regard $u$ as a constant term.

Comment: You're welcome, I think your answers are ok now.